# Wordpress custom post type redirects me to posts

Tags: wordpress

if i'm on the custom post type edit page and click either "Edit Publications" or "Create" link in the menu i always get redirected to the general posts page!

```
$labels = array(
            'name'               => 'Edit Publications',
            'singular_name'      => 'Edit Publications',
            'edit_item'          => 'Edit Publications'
        );
        $args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'public'            => true,
            'publicly_queryable'=> true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_in_nav'       => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'map_meta_cap'      => true,
            'hierarchical'      => false,
            'supports'          => array(''),
            'has_archive'       => true,
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'publication')
        );
```

if i enter the wp-admin page the first time or i'm currently not editing any post the url is different and is working fine

e.g
currently i'm on the dashboard page and the link to "Edit Publications" is

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=mfl_publication
```

if i'm on the custom post type edit page the link to "Edit Publications" is

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php/edit.php?post_type=mfl_publication
```

i've no idea why
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function create_example()
{
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'example'); // Register Taxonomies for Category
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'example');
    register_post_type('example', // Register Custom Post Type
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('example', 'example'), // Rename these to suit
                'singular_name' => __('Comunicado', 'example'),
                'add_new' => __('Add New', 'example'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New Comunicado', 'example'),
                'edit' => __('Edit', 'example'),
                'edit_item' => __('Edit Comunicado', 'example'),
                'new_item' => __('New Comunicado', 'example'),
                'view' => __('View Comunicado', 'example'),
                'view_item' => __('View Comunicado', 'example'),
                'search_items' => __('Search Comunicado', 'example'),
                'not_found' => __('Nothing Found', 'example'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing Found in Trash', 'example')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true, // Allows your posts to behave like Hierarchy Pages
            'has_archive' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'thumbnail'
            ), // Go to Dashboard Custom HTML5 Blank post for supports
            'can_export' => true, // Allows export in Tools > Export
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'category' )
        ));
}


add_action('init', 'create_example'); // Add our HTML5 Blank Custom Post Type
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Worked after having removed the `rewrite` property, then disabling and re-enabling the plugin.